# Multiple Instances Of The Same Computer Under Network

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, windows-server-2008-r2

Can anyone tell me why we have multiple instances of the same computer (SALLY) under network in the open file dialog.  Please see the image below.

This is not an issue in itself, however I am wondering if it is related to some file corruption issues we have been having lately.

All pc's are windows 7.  Server is Windows Server 2008 R2. We are using folder redirection, roaming profiles and offline files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a wireless network on site as well? Is it possible that the client in question has two active network connections, a wired and a wireless connection and when your client is scanning the network for netbios names it is finding both addresses and resolving the same name for both.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes we do have a wireless router on the network. However the computer in question does not have a wireless card and the only network connection is the LAN wired one.  The problem seems to be related to roaming user profiles and offline files.  Since I have disabled these features on the PC for testing purposes, the problem has stopped along with the corrupt files issue.  I am becoming more convinced the issues are related.